# How to join 3 tables properly to get a result if user is attending in the event

Tags: mysql

So I have three tables; users, events and user_events.

Users-table stores all the information about user, events table will store all the events which can be viewed by all the users plus a foreign key row of user's id so that the app can know who created that particular event. Last table, user_events, stores event_id and user_id. I need to do join these three tables together so that i can get a result if that particular user is attending into that particular event.

So far I've tried with this query without any luck:

```
SELECT events.*, user_events.user_id AS attending FROM events
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = events.creatoruserid 
LEFT JOIN user_events ON user_events.user_id = users.user_id;
```

The concept is that I need to do a check within my app and check if user is attending in that particular event and if so, he/she can remove the attendance and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, the user_events table is actually the table although I mentioned the attending table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the event creator is getting mixed into the query while you are trying to grab the attendees. It also seems like you don't need to join with the users table, since none of the fields are used.

```
SELECT events.*, user_events.user_id AS attending FROM events
LEFT JOIN user_events ON user_events.event_id = events.event_id;
```

Edit:
If you want only the events for a single user

```
SELECT events.*, user_events.user_id AS attending FROM events
LEFT JOIN user_events ON user_events.event_id = events.event_id
WHERE user_events.user_id = ?1;
AND events.event_id = ?2;
```

Where `?1` is the id of the user you want to check and `?2` is the id of the event you want to see if the user is attending

Comment: Well, this doesn't work at the way it should. More than one user can attend in to events.

Comment: The way I understand your schema, user_events stores one entry for every user attending an event. If that is the case, the above query will give you a result set containing one row for every attendee, and the details of the event. If that is not what you are trying to do, maybe you can rephrase the question.

Comment: Yes that is true, the query will give me a result set containing one row for every attendee. However, this doesn't work in my app since it's now showing some events the amount of time of how many user's have already attended in the event. That is because of the result set.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the result to look like, could you please clarify?

Comment: I want to show all the events for all the registered users. All users will have an option to participate into these events and if they already are participated, they can remove their attend. What I'm asking is can I somehow, with a single query, to check if the currently logged in user is already attended to that particular event
without affecting all the users?

Comment: Think it this way. Let's say I have a Facebook and I can see status updates.
One of my friends (or another user) in the Facebook has already liked the status update I'd like to like also.
After I click the like button, I have a choice to "dislike" it. When I click "like" or "dislike" it will only affect on me. 

The above query you've given me will return the same
event multiple times because it will give me a result for every attendee and that's why I can participate into those events
multiple times even though I've already attended into them.

Comment: Well you are into application logic now, you need to process the results in whatever programming language your app is written in and dos something with them. What I have given you is two queries: one to list all registrations + event details, and one to tell you whether a specific user is registered for a specific event. Those queries seem to answer the question as you have stated it

Comment: Yes actually those examples provided enough info and I was able to figured it out. Cheers!